# Replace multiple substrings in a Pandas series with a value

Tags: python, string, pandas, python-2.7, series

All,

To replace one string in one particular column I have done this and it worked fine:

```
dataUS['sec_type'].str.strip().str.replace("LOCAL","CORP")
```

I would like now to replace multiple strings with one string say replace `["LOCAL", "FOREIGN", "HELLO"]` with `"CORP"`

How can make it work? the code below didn't work

```
dataUS['sec_type'].str.strip().str.replace(["LOCAL", "FOREIGN", "HELLO"], "CORP")
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can perform this task by forming a |-separated string. This works because [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) accepts regex:

> Replace occurrences of pattern/regex in the Series/Index with some
>   other string. Equivalent to str.replace() or re.sub().

This avoids the need to create a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['LOCAL TEST', 'TEST FOREIGN', 'ANOTHER HELLO', 'NOTHING']})

pattern = '|'.join(['LOCAL', 'FOREIGN', 'HELLO'])

df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(pattern, 'CORP')

#               A
# 0     CORP TEST
# 1     TEST CORP
# 2  ANOTHER CORP
# 3       NOTHING
```

Comment: Your solutions worked best for me. Thank you.  I also liked the solution proposed (but was deleted i think) dataUS.replace({"sec_type": { 'POOL' : "OTHERS", 'ABS' : "OTHERS"}})

Comment: Would the downvoter care to suggest a problem with this method?

Comment: This did not work for me, is it because I'm using Python 2?. Also you didn't explain why it works (which would be a better answer) but I'm inferring that this is a regex format? I am not familiar with Python 3, but I don't see that documented here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace

Comment: This works for me (python 3.6 / pandas 0.19.2), maybe you are using an older version of pandas and/or python. OP did accept it, though..

Comment: Also, I downvoted because I think using the built in pandas suggested by Rakesh is vastly superior (even to my own answer)

Comment: @JeffEllen, but Rakesh's answer (like yours) does not work for substrings.

Answer (score 14):

`replace` can accept `dict` , os we just create a dict for those values need to be replaced

```
dataUS['sec_type'].str.strip().replace(dict(zip(["LOCAL", "FOREIGN", "HELLO"], ["CORP"]*3)),regex=True)
```

Info of the dict

```
dict(zip(["LOCAL", "FOREIGN", "HELLO"], ["CORP"]*3))
Out[585]: {'FOREIGN': 'CORP', 'HELLO': 'CORP', 'LOCAL': 'CORP'}
```

The reason why you receive the error ,

[str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is different from [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: Try instead `dict.fromkeys(["LOCAL", "FOREIGN", "HELLO"], 'CORP')`

Comment: I have tried both suggested solutions and get the error TypeError: replace() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: Yes, me too... I have a different solution

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ hah like this one , even with your improvement ,still

Answer (score 12):

The answer of @Rakesh is very neat but does not allow for substrings. With a small change however, it does.

1. Use a replacement dictionary because it makes it much more generic
2. Add the keyword argument `regex=True` to `Series.replace()` (not `Series.str.replace`) This does two things actually: It changes your replacement to regex replacement, which is much more powerful but you will have to escape special characters. Beware for that. Secondly it will make the replace work on substrings instead of the entire string. Which is really cool!

```
replacement = {
    "LOCAL": "CORP",
    "FOREIGN": "CORP",
    "HELLO": "CORP"
}

dataUS['sec_type'].replace(replacement, regex=True)
```

**Full code example**

```
dataUS = pd.DataFrame({'sec_type': ['LOCAL', 'Sample text LOCAL', 'Sample text LOCAL sample FOREIGN']})

replacement = {
    "LOCAL": "CORP",
    "FOREIGN": "CORP",
    "HELLO": "CORP"
}

dataUS['sec_type'].replace(replacement, regex=True)
```

**Output**

```
0                            CORP
1                            CORP
2                Sample text CORP
3    Sample text CORP sample CORP
Name: sec_type, dtype: object
```

Comment: This solution is comparatively slow than using multiple replace calls on a column one by one.

Answer (score 5):

@JJP answer is a good one if you have a long list. But if you have just two or three then you can simply use the '|' within the pattern. Make sure to add `regex=True` parameter.

Clearly `.str.strip()` is not a requirement but is good practise.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['LOCAL TEST', 'TEST FOREIGN', 'ANOTHER HELLO', 'NOTHING']})

df['A'] = df['A'].str.strip().str.replace("LOCAL|FOREIGN|HELLO", "CORP", regex=True)
```

output

```
    A
0   CORP TEST
1   TEST CORP
2   ANOTHER CORP
3   NOTHING
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but when I tried using this on the column names `df.columns.str.replace(' '|'/'|'-','_', regex = True)` I got an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'". What did I do wrong here?

Comment: try ```df.columns.str.strip().str.replace('[\s\/\-]','_', regex = True)```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cam! It works. Apparently it's due to my poor regex knowledge. I suppose `\s` captures whitespaces. What was wrong with my method tho?

Answer (score 2):

**Function to replace multiple values in pandas Series:**

```
def replace_values(series, to_replace, value):
    for i in to_replace:
        series = series.str.replace(i, value)
    return series
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dataUS.replace({"sec_type": { 'LOCAL' : "CORP", 'FOREIGN' : "CORP"}})
```

Comment: This is beter than my solution because it uses pandas native method, which I overlooked when focusing on what I knew was the problem in str.replace()

Comment: This does not work for substrings..  You need `pd.Series.str.replace`, not `pd.Series.replace`.

Comment: @jpp sorry I don’t understand

Comment: Look up difference between `pd.Series.replace` [requires exact string match] and `pd.Series.str.replace` [replaces substrings]. They are different methods and do different things.