# How to clear the numbers inside the square bracket on Panda Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Data Frame is df2, column I want to clean is 'Official Cause'. The character I want to clean is the square bracket, [] which has numbers inside. For instance, [9], [26], [38]. Each row has one square bracket with number in the same column. By using the expression below, I can remove the closing and the opening of the square brackets, but it does not include the  removal of the numbers inside.

```
df2['Official Cause']=df2['Official Cause'].replace('[26]', ' ').
```

Please I need help, please show me simple formula that works for Pandas Frame. Thanks.

Comment: Please always respond if your question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture brackets as whole and replace.

df2["Official Cause'] = df2["Official Cause'] 
 .str.replace('`\[ .+\]`','')

Comment: Thank you very much, df2["Official Cause"].str.replace(r'[.*] ?', "").str.strip() it has removed the square brackets and numbers inside from the column, ,'Official Cause'. But, it failed to remove the square brackets and numbers from the whole document. I tried to remove the same characters from the whole DataFrame called df2. When I applied the following codes, it gave me error by saying dataframe has no str. attribute. df2.str.replace(r'[.*] ?', "").str.strip() error: DataFrame has no str attribute Please find a find a solution to this error. Thanks! – Greeshma Reddy

Answer (score 0):

pandas.Series.str.replace actually accepts regex, so it is possible to remove multiple values with the same expression. Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple substrings in a Pandas series with a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413005/replace-multiple-substrings-in-a-pandas-series-with-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex -> `r'\[.*\] ?'`
suppose your df is this:

```
    column_a
0   [0.00536237]20
1   [0.00652899]
2   [0.00579218]
```

---

```
df["column_a"].str.replace(r'\[.*\] ?', "").str.strip()
```

---

**Output:**

```
0    20
1      
2      
Name: column_a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if the question is resolved.

Comment: Thank you very much,

df2["Official Cause"].str.replace(r'\[.*\] ?', "").str.strip()

it has removed the square brackets and numbers inside from the column, ,'Official Cause'.
But, it failed to remove the square brackets and numbers from the whole document.
I tried to remove the same characters from the whole DataFrame called df2.
When I applied the following codes, it gave me error by saying dataframe has no str. attribute.

df2.str.replace(r'\[.*\] ?', "").str.strip()

error: DataFrame has no str attribute

Please find a find a solution to this error. Thanks!

Comment: post your dataframe then. edit your question and add your dataframe only few rows. do `df.head()` and put the output here.