# Replace apostrophes and curly brackets with blank space in multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table (dataframe) where multiple string columns contain curly brackets and apostrophes, which I am trying to replace with a blank space:

[image: Table]

I started with the `genre1` column but I keep getting a key error.

This is the code I am trying to remove curly bracket:

```
movies['genre1'].replace(to_replace=["}"],value="",inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hello Norbert! Could you please paste your sample code & data, You should probably do that as some people might downvote this question and causing you not to ask questions anymore , this is basically what STACKOVERFLOW is. Thank you!

Comment: I posted diagram of table, thanks for your message!

Comment: Great! that's nice :) let's just hope those downvotes will be undo by whoever did that :)

Comment: Please do not post data/code/error messages as images. Post the code/data directly here on SO. I suggest also reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple substrings in a Pandas series with a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413005/replace-multiple-substrings-in-a-pandas-series-with-a-value)

Comment: Yes let's hope! Question is solved as well! Thank you for everyone's help

Comment: I edited your question title and body to help make it clear why this is not a duplicate, and why it's worth leaving open and not downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work!

```
movies['genre1'] = movies['genre1'].str.replace("}","")
```

What you are doing is will look exactly for '}', and wherever the value of the cell will be exactly equal to }, it will replace. So, you need to use the attr str.

Comment: I made an update, there was typoo before. Re-run and see if you face the error again then add error details' screenshot.

Comment: yes it worked thank you!! now to remove the apostrophe, I have to use the same code but replace curly brackets with apostrophe right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `replace` with a key-value pair -

```
replace_map = {'}':'',']':''}

genre_columns = table.columns[table.columns.str.contains('genre')]

table.loc[:,genre_columns] = table.replace(genre_columns)
```