# pandas string replace is not replacing all selections

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
dfsupport = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['8/12/2020','8/12/2020','13/1/2020','24/5/2020','31/10/2020','11/7/2020','11/7/2020'],
                          'Category': ['Table','Chair','Cushion','Table','Chair','Mats','Mats'],
                          'Sales': ['1 table','3chairs','8 cushions','3Tables','12 Chairs','12Mats','4Mats'],
                          'Paid': ['Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes',],
                          'Amount': ['93.78','$51.99','44.99','38.24','£29.99','29 only','18']
                          })
```

I am attempting to replace currency signs with blanks, but the below does not work.

```
patternv='|'.join(['$', '£'])
dfsupport['Amount'] = dfsupport['Amount'].str.replace(patternv,'')
```

Why does this not work?

Print the dataframe after the above:

```
          Date Category       Sales Paid   Amount
0   8/12/2020    Table     1 table  Yes    93.78
1   8/12/2020    Chair     3chairs  Yes   $51.99
2   13/1/2020  Cushion  8 cushions  Yes    44.99
3   24/5/2020    Table     3Tables  Yes    38.24
4  31/10/2020    Chair   12 Chairs   No   £29.99
5   11/7/2020     Mats      12Mats  Yes  29 only
6   11/7/2020     Mats       4Mats  Yes       18
         Date Category      Sales Paid  Amount
1   8/12/2020    Chair    3chairs  Yes  $51.99
4  31/10/2020    Chair  12 Chairs   No  £29.99
```

I did follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413005/replace-multiple-substrings-in-a-pandas-series-with-a-value), so not sure why mine isn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing two important things:

- escaping the regex characters with [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) (`$` means "end-of-string")
- defining the `regex=True` mode of [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) (now `False` by default)

```
import re

patternv='|'.join(map(re.escape, ['$', '£']))
dfsupport['Amount'] = dfsupport['Amount'].str.replace(patternv, '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
         Date Category       Sales Paid   Amount
0   8/12/2020    Table     1 table  Yes    93.78
1   8/12/2020    Chair     3chairs  Yes    51.99
2   13/1/2020  Cushion  8 cushions  Yes    44.99
3   24/5/2020    Table     3Tables  Yes    38.24
4  31/10/2020    Chair   12 Chairs   No    29.99
5   11/7/2020     Mats      12Mats  Yes  29 only
6   11/7/2020     Mats       4Mats  Yes       18
```

Answer (score 2):

First escape regex characters in generator comprehension and then specify `regex=True` for [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for replace substrings:

```
import re

patternv='|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in ['$', '£'])
dfsupport['Amount'] = dfsupport['Amount'].str.replace(patternv,'', regex=True)
print (dfsupport)
         Date Category       Sales Paid   Amount
0   8/12/2020    Table     1 table  Yes    93.78
1   8/12/2020    Chair     3chairs  Yes    51.99
2   13/1/2020  Cushion  8 cushions  Yes    44.99
3   24/5/2020    Table     3Tables  Yes    38.24
4  31/10/2020    Chair   12 Chairs   No    29.99
5   11/7/2020     Mats      12Mats  Yes  29 only
6   11/7/2020     Mats       4Mats  Yes       18
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
dfsupport['Amount'] = dfsupport['Amount'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)')
```

Output:

```
         Date Category       Sales Paid Amount
0   8/12/2020    Table     1 table  Yes  93.78
1   8/12/2020    Chair     3chairs  Yes  51.99
2   13/1/2020  Cushion  8 cushions  Yes  44.99
3   24/5/2020    Table     3Tables  Yes  38.24
4  31/10/2020    Chair   12 Chairs   No  29.99
5   11/7/2020     Mats      12Mats  Yes     29
6   11/7/2020     Mats       4Mats  Yes     18
```

Comment: Alternative: `(\d+\.?\d?)` ;)

Comment: A very nice one, @mozway! Thanks!